# SQL Server convert row values to columns

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have an SQL table like this

```
 Name1    Name2    Department1    Department2    Location1   Location2  
 ----------------------------------------------------------------------
 Jhon     Alex     IT             Marketing      London      Seattle
 Mark     Dan      Sales          R&D            Paris       Tokyo
```

How can I query these results in this format:

```
 Name        Department      Location
 ---------------------------------------
 Jhon        IT              London
 Alex        Marketing       Seattle
 Mark        Sales           Paris
 Dan         R&D             Tokyo
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use `cross apply`

**[DEMO](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=42772e975210d35884b472b6295b60ce)**

```
select name,department,location
from t
cross apply
(
  values(name1,department1,location1),(name2,department2,location2)
)cc (name, department,location)
```

OUTPUT:

```
name    department  location
Jhon    IT           London
Alex    Marketing    Seattle
Mark    Sales        Paris
Dan     R&D T        Tokyo
```

Answer (score 4):

You could try to use SQL Server's `UNPIVOT` operator, but honestly a plain union query might even perform better:

```
SELECT Name1 AS Name, Department1 AS Department, Location1 AS Location FROM yourTable
UNION ALL
SELECT Name2, Department2, Location2 FROM yourTable;
```

Regarding your expected ordering, there is no sort of id column in your original table which maintains to which name pair each record belongs.  So, what I have written above might be the best we can do here.

Answer (score 0):

Try This:

```
DECLARE @TestDemo AS TABLE(Name1 VARCHAR(10),Name2 VARCHAR(10),Department1 VARCHAR(10),Department2 VARCHAR(10),Location1 VARCHAR(10),Location2 VARCHAR(10))

    INSERT INTO @TestDemo VALUES('Jhon','Alex','IT','Marketing','London','Seattle')
    INSERT INTO @TestDemo VALUES('Mark','Dan','Sales','R&D','Paris','Tokyo')

    SELECT Name1 'Name',Department1 'Department',Location1  'Location' FROM @TestDemo
    UNION ALL
    SELECT Name2 'Name',Department2 'Department',Location2  'Location' FROM @TestDemo
```